# After "npx create-react-app" "npm start" fails with following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

```
Node v12.18.4
Npm 6.14.11
react-scripts 4.0.1
```

Hello, this is not my first react-app but I am getting an error that makes no sense.
After using "npx create-react-app" cd into my app and "npm start" I am getting this error

```
/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Documents/Personal/TechnicalTests/informa/todo-app/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at processModule (/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Documents/Personal/TechnicalTests/informa/todo-app/node_modules/eslint-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:93:38)
    at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Documents/Personal/TechnicalTests/informa/todo-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:5:1)
    at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Documents/Personal/TechnicalTests/informa/todo-app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Documents/Personal/TechnicalTests/informa/todo-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:781:30
    at MultiModule.build (/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Documents/Personal/TechnicalTests/informa/todo-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiModule.js:39:10)
    at Compilation.buildModule (/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Documents/Personal/TechnicalTests/informa/todo-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:739:10)
    at /Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Documents/Personal/TechnicalTests/informa/todo-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1111:12
    at MultiModuleFactory.create (/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Documents/Personal/TechnicalTests/informa/todo-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/MultiModuleFactory.js:18:3)
    at /Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Documents/Personal/TechnicalTests/informa/todo-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1063:18
    at Semaphore.acquire (/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Documents/Personal/TechnicalTests/informa/todo-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/Semaphore.js:29:4)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! todo-app@0.1.0 start: `./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the todo-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/pablodeyzaguirre/.npm/_logs/2021-01-19T13_21_16_205Z-debug.log
MBP-de-Pablo:todo-app pablodeyzaguirre$
```

I have deleted node_modules and installed again, installed react-scripts globally, updated npm & react version.
The full log of the error is:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.11
3 info using node@v12.18.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle todo-app@0.1.0~prestart: todo-app@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle todo-app@0.1.0~start: todo-app@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle todo-app@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle todo-app@0.1.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Documents/Personal/TechnicalTests/informa/todo-app/node_modules/.bin:/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/.symfony/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/.symfony/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Library/Android/sdk/emulator:/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Library/Android/sdk/emulator:/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
9 verbose lifecycle todo-app@0.1.0~start: CWD: /Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Documents/Personal/TechnicalTests/informa/todo-app
10 silly lifecycle todo-app@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', './node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start' ]
11 silly lifecycle todo-app@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle todo-app@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: todo-app@0.1.0 start: `./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid todo-app@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/pablodeyzaguirre/Documents/Personal/TechnicalTests/informa/todo-app
16 verbose Darwin 20.2.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.4
19 verbose npm  v6.14.11
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error todo-app@0.1.0 start: `./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the todo-app@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

If someone has encountered this problem before pls help, I have been looking around in google and stackoverflow with no luck

Answer (score 1):

Encountered basically the same issue as you. For us it ended up being special quotes in our env variables. Once we removed those, it all worked ... 
Took a work day to figure this one out!

Comment: If i remember correctly for me it was a problem with the version of create-react-app. Fun times anyways.